# SQL Server - Update table1 with max condition in table1

Tags: sql-server, updates

I'm fairly new to SQL.  This site has been a great resource and I found answers to many questions so far.  Now I'm a little stuck, so it's time for my first question.

I'm working in SQL Server 2012.  How do I update `FLAG = 'Y'` when `START_DATE = (SELECT CONTRACT, MIN(START_DATE) FROM #CONTR GROUP BY CONTRACT)` ?

```
CREATE TABLE #CONTR
(
CONTRACT        INT ,       -- PRIMARY KEY COL1
CONTRACT_LINE   INT ,       -- PRIMARY KEY COL2
START_DATE      INT ,       -- 0 = CURRENT MONTH, -3 = THREE MONTHS IN PAST
FLAG            VARCHAR(1)  -- 'Y' OR 'N', DEFAULTED TO 'N' WHEN TABLE POPULATED
)
```

This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you sidux and Giannis!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1,1,100,'N')
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1,1,200,'N')

INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2,1,100,'N')
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2,1,200,'N')

UPDATE
    c
SET
    c.FLAG = 'Y'
FROM
    #CONTR c
    JOIN (
           SELECT
            CONTRACT _CONTRACT ,
            MAX(START_DATE) _START_DATE
           FROM
            #CONTR
           GROUP BY
            CONTRACT
         ) mc ON c.CONTRACT = mc.[_CONTRACT] AND c.START_DATE = mc.[_START_DATE]
```

Another way to do that. It is absolutely the same, just the syntax is different:

```
UPDATE
    c
SET
    c.FLAG = 'Y'
FROM
    #CONTR c
    CROSS APPLY (
           SELECT
            c1.CONTRACT _CONTRACT 
           FROM
            #CONTR c1
            WHERE c1.CONTRACT = c.CONTRACT
           GROUP BY
            CONTRACT
            HAVING MAX(c1.START_DATE) = c.START_DATE  
         ) mc;
```

And the results:

```
SELECT * FROM #CONTR
CONTRACT    CONTRACT_LINE   START_DATE  FLAG
1   1   100 N
1   1   200 Y
2   1   100 N
2   1   200 Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE #CONTR
SET    FLAG = 'Y'
FROM #CONTR C1
     JOIN 
     (SELECT CONTRACT, MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE FROM #CONTR GROUP BY CONTRACT) C2
     ON C1.START_DATE = C2.START_DATE
```

Comment: There is an another answer similar to this which joins also on CONTRACT. I have purposely left that out of the join, as i am not sure if it is needed in this case.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Why are you commenting on your own answer instead of editing? Also, I would think you would know this already (you've been a member for almost 2 years now) but ["Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott I do not think my comment is yet a part of the solution as i do am not sure if the OP wants it that way or the other. If i would know that i would add it in my answer. By the way, i do not see any flag.